# i have a program that takes input a string that's called search which is the target and i want to search in the csv file if the "search" is there

Tags: c++, c, csv, file, fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void myFgets(char str[], int n);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: csv <csv file path>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        char ch = ' ', search[100], dh = ' ';
        int row = 1;
        printf("Enter value to search: ");
        myFgets(search, 100);

        FILE* fileRead = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (fileRead == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening the file!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while ((ch = (char)fgetc(fileRead)) != EOF)
        {
            char str[100];
            int i = 0, pos = ftell(fileRead);
            while ((dh = (char)fgetc(fileRead)) != ',')
            {
                str[i] = dh;
                i++;
            }
            fseek(fileRead, pos + 1, SEEK_SET);
            if (strstr("\n", str) != NULL)
            {
                row++;
            }
            if (strstr(search, str) != NULL)
            {
                printf("Value was found in row: %d\n", row);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*
Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
input: the buffer to read into, the number of chars to read
*/
void myFgets(char* str, int n)
{
    fgets(str, n, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
```

in line 39 im getting an error but idk why it seems like im doing everything fine
im trying to loop through the rows and split them by the ',' so i could check if search == to it but its not wokring
im using function strstr to compare 2 strings with each other it works fine and all but the only problem is at the dh
i did fseek after the dh so i dont write in the wrong place in the ch loop

Comment: Your first step is to figure out whether you're writing C or C++ code. They are two completely different languages. Is your intent to write a C or a C++ program?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to terminate the string.

```
while ((dh = (char)fgetc(fileRead)) != ',')
{
    str[i] = dh;
    i++;
}
str[i] = '\0'; /* add this to terminate the string */
```

Also it looks like `if (strstr(search, str) != NULL)` should be `if (strstr(str, search) != NULL)` to search for the value to search from the contents of the file.